# Select by Location using first points of polyline

Tags: arcpy, point, line, select-by-location

I am trying to select a point from a point layer that intersect a polyline layers firstpoint and using arcpy.  I am getting an error "*ExecuteError: ERROR 000622: Failed to execute (Select Layer By Location). Parameters are not valid. ERROR 000623: Invalid value type for parameter select_features.*"

```
import arcpy

def main():

    arcpy.env.workspace = r'D:\My Documents\SR91_FeasibilityStudy\GISData\SR-91.gdb'

    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management('Build2035', 'plLayer') #polyline Layer
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management('Build2035_pts_CollectEvents', 'ptLayer') #point Layer

    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor('plLayer',("Shape@","OID@")) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
           arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management('ptLayer','intersect',row[0].firstPoint)
           result = arcpy.GetCount_management('ptLayer')
           print result
```

Comment: You can save the first point of each Polyline using "Feature Vertices To Points", enter START as the 3rd parameter. Then intersect the two Point layers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to perform a selection for each row, as your script indicates, you need to convert your `point` object to a `geometry` object. Here's a very messy line of code that will do so:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management('ptLayer','intersect',arcpy.Geometry ("point", row[0].firstPoint, arcpy.Describe ('Build2035').spatialReference))
```

If you want to perform a single selection based off of all first points, create a new feature class and export your first points to it using a cursor (or if you have an advanced license, use `Feature Vertices To Points` as described by klewis in the comments).

Something like this (untested):

```
import arcpy

def main():

    arcpy.env.workspace = r'D:\My Documents\SR91_FeasibilityStudy\GISData\SR-91.gdb'
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management('Build2035_pts_CollectEvents', 'ptLayer') #point Layer

    #Create empty point feature class for first points
    outPath = arcpy.env.workspace
    arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management (outPath, "FirstPoints", "POINT", spatial_reference = 'Build2035')

    #add firstpoints to feature class
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor ('Build2035', "SHAPE@") as sCurs:
        with arcpy.da.InsertCursor ("FirstPoints", "SHAPE@") as iCurs:
            for geom, in sCurs:
                row = (geom.firstPoint,)
                iCurs.insertRow (row)


    #select points by first points feature class
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management('ptLayer','intersect', "FirstPoints")
    result = arcpy.GetCount_management('ptLayer').getOutput (0)
    print result
```